# JavaScript Combinations of Arbitrary number of Arrays and their Indices

Tags: javascript, arrays, permutation

I am dealing with a slightly weird problem of permuting through n number of given arrays.

Let's say I have 3 arrays (but there could be more):

- Array A with length 2: **var A = new Array(1);**
- Array B with length 2: **var B = new Array(1);**
- Array C with length 3: **var C = new Array(2);**

I want to calculate all possible permutations of the lenghts of these 3 arrays.

The result should looks something like this:

- A[0],B[0],C[0]
- A[0],B[0],C[1]
- A[0],B[0],C[2]
- A[0],B[1],C[0]
- A[0],B[1],C[1]
- A[0],B[1],C[2]
- A[1],B[0],C[0]
- A[1],B[0],C[1]
- A[1],B[0],C[2]
- A[1],B[1],C[0]
- A[1],B[1],C[1]
- A[1],B[1],C[2]
  ...

I actually need the output like this. I don't' care about the values assigned to the arrays at the point.

Unfortunately, I don't have any working code to share. I'll update this post as soon as I come up with something that even remotely works.

Comment: so you are more looking for combinations of the given indices. what have you tried?

Comment: *"Array A with length 2: var A = new Array(1);"* That array has a length of 1, not 2. *"Array C with length 3: var C = new Array(2);"* Similarly, that array's length is 2, not 3. If you give a number as the only argument to `new Array`, it specifies the length to assign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a nested reduce structure for an arbitrary lenght of the given array with values.

```js
var words = [['quick', 'lazy'], ['brown', 'black', 'grey'], ['fox', 'dog']],
    result = words.reduce((a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => [].concat(v, w))), []));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

You could take a more detailed approach, where you could add some logic to the collected result where the pushing takes place.

```js
function getCombinations(array) {
    function iter(i, p) {
        if (i === array.length) {
            result.push(p); // <==================== use the items
            return;
        }
        array[i].forEach(function (a) {
            iter(i + 1, p.concat(a));
        });
    }

    var result = [];

    iter(0, []);
    return result;
}

var words = [['quick', 'lazy'], ['brown', 'black', 'grey'], ['fox', 'dog']],
    result = getCombinations(words);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hi Nina, awesome work. This really works, I've tried it here (https://jsfiddle.net/jarosciak/x67dh5to/3/) and it produces exactly what I want. However, I don't understand this code enough to get inside the loop itself. I don't want to just output the combinations at the end of the calculation. I need to be able to catch every single result and do something with it. How do I do that?

Comment: Please let me know if this could be rewritten in a way, that I can catch the each of the combinations as they are being calculated. That would essentially provide the full answer to my question. Thanks.

Comment: @jjj, please see edit for a more traditional approach.

Comment: Oh wow, that is just beautiful. Thank you so much. This is something I wouldn't come up with on my own.